# Gradle How to build several versions of a jar with different dependencies

Tags: gradle

If somebody tried to solve similar problem before, please share your solution. In my gradle file I have different subproject. As of right now I am able to build rest-client with core, but there could be situation when rest-client should be also be build with db-client subproject. Basically the idea is I need to be able to build rest-client with different dependency. Let say one task builds rest-client with dependency to one project and another task build rest-client with  dependency on two subproject.

```
project(':core') {
    apply plugin: "groovy"
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5'
        testCompile "org.testng:testng:6.8.21"
    }
}

//rest-client Project specific stuff
project(':rest-client') {
    apply plugin: "groovy"
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'
        compile project(':core')
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5'
        testCompile "org.testng:testng:6.8.21"

    }
    jar {
        from configurations.runtime
    }
}

//db-client Project specific stuff
project(':db-client') {
    apply plugin: "groovy"
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile project(':core')
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5'
        compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37'
        //compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:2.3.1'
        compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-client-groovy:0.10.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create multiple compile tasks and for them also jar tasks.
Create different configurations and use them in your compile tasks

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: in case of maven it's all straight forward but in case of gradle it 's not as straight forward. Please provide an example.

Comment: @Hillkor    For example I have this version of my subproject. In this case it's only have one dependency on core, but there will be a case when it will have another subproject in it. I would like to have multiple version of the same subproject and build the one I need.

Comment: <!-- language: lang-js -->project(':rest-client') {
    apply plugin: "groovy"
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'
        compile project(':core')
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5'
        testCompile "org.testng:testng:6.8.21"

    }
    jar {
        from configurations.runtime
    }
}<!-- language: lang-js -->

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, if you still need something like this here is an example.

```
apply plugin: "groovy"

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
  projectDep
  libraryDep
}

project('core') {
  apply plugin: "java"

}

dependencies {
  projectDep project(':core')
  libraryDep 'my.project:project:0.1.0'

  compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'
  compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5'
  testCompile "org.testng:testng:6.8.21"
}

jar {
  from configurations.libraryDep
}

task projectJar(type: Jar) {
  appendix = 'project'
  from sourceSets.main.output, configurations.projectDep, configurations.runtime
}
```

You have then 2 jar tasks. The jar takes all declared dependencies from compile,runtime and libraryDep and the projectJar takes compile,runtime and projectDep.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like your moxy.