# In gradle: How to build two fat jars, identical except for different dependency?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project that successfully builds a fat jar (i.e. containing its own dependencies).  What I need, however, is for it to build two jars:

- one with this dependency: compile('postgresql:postgresql:8.4-702.jdbc4')
- the other with this dependency: compile('org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1.jre7')

Apart from that, they should be identical.

Can I do this in gradle?

I have the requirement that I can only call gradle once (i.e. can't call gradle once for each jar).

The relevant parts of my gradle file look like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.4.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

jar {
    baseName = 'demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    ...

    compile('org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1.jre7') // or compile('postgresql:postgresql:8.4-702.jdbc4')

    ...
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

...

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this helps anyone, this is how I did it:

1. extract the existing jar into a folder:

   ```
   task extractJar(type: Copy, dependsOn: [otherTasksThatBuildFirstJar]) {
       from zipTree(jar.archivePath)
       into 'build/jarContents'
   }
   ```
2. delete the dependency that I don't want:

   ```
   task deletePostgres(type: Delete, dependsOn: [extractJar]) {
       delete fileTree('build/jarContents/lib') {
           include '**/postgres*.jar'
       }
   }
   ```
3. add in the dependency that I do want:

   ```
   task replacePostgres(type: Copy, dependsOn: [deletePostgres]) {
       from 'lib/postgresql-8.4-702.jdbc4.jar'
       into 'build/jarContents/lib'
   }
   ```
4. build the second jar:

   ```
   task buildSecondJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: [replacePostgres]) {
       baseName 'my-second-jar'
       entryCompression ZipEntryCompression.STORED //prevents compression of jars
       from  files('build/jarContents')
       destinationDir project.rootDir
       manifest {
           attributes(
                   'Start-Class': 'com.somewhere.MyApplication',
                   'Spring-Boot-Classes': 'BOOT-INF/classes/',
                   'Spring-Boot-Lib': 'BOOT-INF/lib/',
                   'Spring-Boot-Version': '1.5.8.RELEASE',
                   'Main-Class': 'org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher'
           )
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If it is okay for you to run gradle once for one jar, a simple command line property and an if block can do the job. Also see here: [Passing properties to a gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065193/passing-properties-to-a-gradle-build)

Also look at duplicate Question: [Gradle How to build several versions of a jar with different dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711521/gradle-how-to-build-several-versions-of-a-jar-with-different-dependencies?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I don't have control over the gradle command being run (I'm using Heroku, which only runs gradle once).  I could invoke two tasks, one for each jar, but (as I'm still a newbie in gradle) I don't know how to invoke jar-building tasks. And I also don't know how to pass a different property through to each task.  Any suggestions?

Comment: follow the links, look at the other answers

Comment: Also add these details about heroku and how gradle is invoked to the question